# How to compare strings in constant time?

Tags: security, rust

How does one safely compare two strings with bounded length in such a way that each comparison takes the same time? Hashing unfortunately has a timing attack vulnerability.

Is there any way to compare two strings without hashing in a way that is not vulnerable to timing-attacks?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt this wiki help me ^^ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack

Comment: Why do you think that hashing is vulnerable to timing attacks? Wouldn't it depend on the particular hash algorithm being used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR: Use assembly.**

---

Constant Time code is *really* hard to pull off. To be truly constant time you need:

- a constant time algorithm,
- a constant time implementation of said algorithm.

---

> What does "constant time algorithm" mean?

The example of string comparison is great. Most of the time, you want the comparison to take as little as possible, which means bailing out at the first difference:

```
fn simple_compare(a: &str, b: &str) -> bool {
    if a.len() != b.len() { return false; }

    for (a, b) in a.bytes().zip(b.bytes()) {
        if a != b { return false; }
    }

    true
}
```

The constant time version algorithm version however should have constant time regardless of the input:

- the input should always have the same size,
- the time taken to compute the result should be identical no matter where the difference is located (if any).

The algorithm Lukas gave is almost right:

```
/// Prerequisite: a.len() == b.len()
fn ct_compare(a: &str, b: &str) -> bool {
    debug_assert!(a.len() == b.len());

    a.bytes().zip(b.bytes())
        .fold(0, |acc, (a, b)| acc | (a ^ b) ) == 0
}
```

---

> What does "constant time implementation" mean?

Even if the algorithm is constant time, the implementation may not be.

If the exact same sequence of CPU instructions is not used, then on some architecture one of the instructions could be faster, while the other is slower, and the implementation would lose.

If the algorithm uses table look-up, then there could be more or less cache misses.

---

> Can you write a constant time implementation of string comparison in Rust?

**No**.

The Rust language could potentially be suited to the task, however *its toolchain is not*:

- the LLVM optimizer will wreak havoc with your algorithm, short-circuiting it, eliminating unnecessary reads, now or in the future,
- the LLVM backends will wreak havoc with your implementation, picking different instructions.

**The short and long is that, today, the only way to access a constant time implementation from Rust is to write said implementation in assembly.**

Comment: Do you think *any* language other than assembly is suitable for such?

Comment: @Shepmaster: I think it's less a matter of language and more a matter of toolchain. I'm pretty sure that a straightforward translation of C, C++ or Rust code could easily be constant time... but today's compilers rarely do straightforward translations.

Comment: FYI: I deleted my answer, so you may or may not want to update the part mentioning my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a crate providing such implementation, you can use [rust-crypto](https://docs.rs/rust-crypto/0.2.36/crypto/index.html) that provides the function [`fixed_time_eq`](https://docs.rs/rust-crypto/0.2.36/crypto/util/fn.fixed_time_eq.html).

The implementation is very similar to the one of Lukas Kalbertodt.